# In Microsoft Luis, how do I model an array of entities?

Tags: node.js, nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

So I am trying to understand user's utterance for selecting an array of entities, here are some example utterances:

```
My choices are 1, 2, 3, and 4
Let's go with Red  Blue  Yellow
How about January and February and March
I want A & B & C
```

So in the example utterances above, I should be able to get the following entities:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[Red,Blue,Yellow]
[January,February,March]
[A,B,C]
```

I don't have the choices before hand so I can't train them.  But I want to be able to understand multiple choices that the user select.  Is this possible within Luis?

I guess I could mimic NLU by just use delimiter and regex to break up the user's input.  But that wont work if the user use different delimiter.  Or if the user append a lot of chatter before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that by creating an Entity of type `Simple` called `Choice` and adding utterances like that and labeling the choices with said entity, like this:

[image]

Luis, as an AI, is very good at recognizing patterns and those utterances have a very definite pattern which is:

Utterance: `Prefix` + `Choice1` + `delimiter` + `Choice2` + `delimiter` + ... + `ChoiceN`

Being

- `Prefix`: "My choices are", "Let's go with", "How about", etc.
- `Choice`: any word
- `delimiter`: ",", "and", " ", etc

That is roughly the pattern that Luis detects, in this case will detect anything after the `prefix` separated by a `delimiter` as a `choice`. So an utterance like

> I want a soda, burger and fries

Will result in:

[image]

Even though we haven't specified Luis that `soda` `burger` and `fries` are valid choices, he still detected them as such!

Here's the Luis model I created for this answer: https://github.com/navelDirt/luis-apps/blob/master/ChoiceDetect/ChoicesApp.json

You can import it in Luis by going to YourApp -> Manage -> Versions -> Import Version

**Edit:**

It should detect `N` choices

[image]

Comment: What if the user select more than 3 choices?  Say 5 or 6 choices. Would Luis be smart enough to add more choices + delimiter even though our training set doesn't cover that?

Comment: It should detect `N` as the pattern is specific, I added another example to the answer